AWS Lambda Functions: Change the URI?
When creating a Lambda Function you can request a "Function URL". It looks something like this:
https://[long string of characters].lambda-url.us-west-1.on.aws/

Is it possible to change that long string of characters to something meaningful (and memorable) like you can do on GCP?
Looking at the template.yaml, I'd expect such an option to be under
Resources/[Function]/Properties/FunctionUrlConfig

perhaps?
I also found AWS::Lambda::Url - AWS CloudFormation but not sure what it is and what to do with it.
Many thanks.

If you have a domain name, you could create a CNAME record that resolves to that Lambda URL.

To answer your question simply: No, it's not possible to change the string in the URL. The only way around that is as John stated above, to use your own domain.
